# How can i get the full path in local.xml file

Tags: layout, magento

Here is my code:

```
<reference name="top.links">
   <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url>checkout/cart</url></action>
</reference>
```

Here how can i get full path of checkout/cart in `<url></url>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to remove that link from the header of the whole site, I would just copy the `checkout.xml` layout file to my custom theme directory to override it, and comment/delete the line where it is added:

```
<reference name="top.links">
    <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
        <!--<action method="addCartLink"></action>--> <!-- remove this -->
        <action method="addCheckoutLink"></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

But if you really need to remove the link via `removeLinkByUrl()`, looking through the core code they usually do this:

```
<action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getRegisterUrl" /></action>
```

Then there is a method called `getRegisterUrl()` in `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Helper/Data.php` which looks like this:

```
public function getRegisterUrl()
{
    return $this->_getUrl('customer/account/create');
}
```

So if you need to get a URL for `checkout/cart` you could set up a custom Helper in a  custom extension which does something similar.

I hope this helps! Good luck!

Comment: It's not working! I tried this in local.xml : `<default><reference name="top.links">
   <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="checkout/getCartUrl" /></action>  
  </reference></default>`

Comment: It looks like `getCartUrl()` is actually in the Url helper instead of the Data helper. Try this instead: `<url helper="checkout/url/getCartUrl" />`