# Removing links from top menu using local.xml

Tags: magento

Does anyone know how I can remove links from the top menu using local.xml.

In the default checkout.xml there is:

```
<reference name="top.links">
    <block type="checkout/links" name="checkout_cart_link">
        <action method="addCartLink"></action>
        <action method="addCheckoutLink"></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

And I would like to remove the addCartLink from the top menu. One way would be just edit the checkout.xml file, but it think it would be a much better solution just to add the remove to my local.xml file, but I can't seem to get the right name to remove. If I do a

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <remove name="top.links" />
    </default>
</layout>
```

That does remove the entire menu, but how do I remove just a single item from the menu using locale.xml?

I am using Magento 1.6

Comment: The free '[Frontend Links Manager](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/MagePsycho/extension/7905/frontend_links_manager)' extension lets you do this from the control panel.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do this in local.xml:

```
<default>
  <reference name="top.links"> 
    <action method="removeLinkByUrl">
      <url helper="checkout/url/getCartUrl" />
    </action> 
  </reference>
</default>
```

It was also my question [How can i get the full path in local.xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6235990/how-can-i-get-the-full-path-in-local-xml-file/6240752)

Comment: The free '[Frontend Links Manager](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/MagePsycho/extension/7905/frontend_links_manager)' extension lets you do this from the control panel.

Comment: FYI for anyone like me who found this 2 years later: this code is for 1.3.x and appears to cause an error in 1.8. Nikhil_K_R's answer worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/12817619/1344515

Comment: FUI anyone passing by nowadays: this works perfectly on 1.9.x

Answer (score 9):

```
<default>
 <reference name="top.links">
    <block type="wishlist/links" name="wishlist_link"/>
    <action method="removeLinkBlock"><blockName>wishlist_link</blockName></action>
 </reference> 
</default>
```

Add this part to your **local.xml**. Writing this under *default* will remove it from **every page**. So adjust it accordingly. I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 4):

It should be:

```
<layout>
     <default>
        <reference name="top.links">
            <reference name="checkout_cart_link">
                <remove name="top-link-cart" />
            </reference>
        </reference>
     </default>
</layout>
```

But you can always copy the **checkout.xml** in your local theme and edit it.

Comment: That did not work -( I know I can copy and edit checkout.xml but I am trying to avoid all that copy+edit of different files just to control the menus. But maybe I just have to do that instead.

Comment: This code will mark the block with the name "top-link-cart" with the remove="1" attribute, meaning it won't be rendered.

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to remove a block. I want to remove a link within the block.

Answer (score 3):

```
<default>
<reference name="top.links">
    <remove name="wishlist_link"/>
</reference>
</default>
```

Add this part to your **local.xml**. That works for me. Just use "remove". That's it.

Comment: Thanks. Also can be useful <remove name="checkout_cart_link"/> to remove cart related items.

Answer (score 1):

**You can remove a link via layout update either**

1. by its name | calling removeLinkBlock($blockName)
2. by its url  | calling removeLinkByUrl($url)
3. overwriting the file were it was added

The functions live in `Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links`

**Option 1**

The removeLinkByUrl() function needs an url as parameter which will usually provided by a helper function in the respective extension. Just grab it there and you can use something like

```
<reference name="top.links">
      <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url helper="customer/getRegisterUrl"/></action>
   </reference>
```

In above case `customer` is the extensions name while `getRegisterUrl` is the function in the helper class.

If your extension isn't providing any function which is returning a link you can try following

```
<reference name="top.links">
   <action method="removeLinkByUrl"><url>ADD_THE_DYNAMIC_LINK_HERE</url></action>
</reference>
```

**Option 2**

If the link was added with a name, like

```
<reference name="top.links">
   <block type="wishlist/links" name="wishlist_link" />
   <action method="addLinkBlock"><blockName>wishlist_link</blockName></action>
</reference>
```

you can just use

```
<reference name="top.links">
   <remove name="wishlist_link"/>
</reference>
```

**or**

```
<default>
 <reference name="top.links">
    <block type="wishlist/links" name="wishlist_link"/>
    <action method="removeLinkBlock"><blockName>wishlist_link</blockName></action>
 </reference> 
</default>
```

**Option 3**

If your link wasn't added with a name and a hardcoded url doesn't work for some reason you can just go ahead and copy the modules layout.xml to your custom theme folder and remove the lines where the link was added.

Answer (score 0):

Hi This removes both the cart and checkout links from top.links in 1.9.3

```
<reference name="top.links"> 
  <action method="removeLinkByUrl">
    <url helper="checkout/url/getCartUrl" />
  </action>
  <action method="removeLinkByUrl">
    <url helper="checkout/url/getCheckoutUrl" />
  </action>
</reference>
```

based on the best accepted answer above but just in case anyone wants to remove both