# Remove 'My Wishlist' and 'Checkout' from header - Magento

Tags: magento

I understand to remove the top links I have to use the Local.xml method which I have done.

However I want to remove the 'My Wishlist' and 'Checkout' links which sit next to the My account drop down in the header?

Any ideas on how to do this ?

My website can be found here...

http://magento-12075-28005-67407.cloudwaysapps.com/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As answered in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769585/removing-links-from-top-menu-using-local-xml), you can do it by adding this you your `local.xml`:

```
<default>
  <reference name="top.links"> 
    <action method="removeLinkByUrl">
      <url helper="checkout/url/getCartUrl" />
    </action> 
    <block type="wishlist/links" name="wishlist_link"/>
    <action method="removeLinkBlock">
      <blockName>wishlist_link</blockName></action>
    </action>
  </reference>
</default>
```

Comment: @Phil You can display template hints to see which blocks beeing rendered. To do this, go to System->Configuration->Developer. Then select "Main Website" as config (on top left) and then under "Debug" you'll find "show template hints, enable it. go back to the website and you'll find red boxes with the paths of the files. Then you'll see which file is responsible for the "Wishlist" and "Checkout" and you can edit them. Hope this helps.